# Question about proof of Liouville' thm. about volume preserving diffeomeorphsims

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

I am trying to understand the following proof:

[image]

What I dont't understand is how $\delta(t,x)$ is differentiated. My first thought was to use
[image]

But I am not sure if I am on the right track here.

Many thanks in advance!

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't say what part of the demonstration is unclear.  The first line is chain rule, $$\frac{\partial \Phi_t(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \Phi_t(x)}{\partial \Phi_s(x)} \cdot \frac{\partial \Phi_s(x)}{\partial x}$$
and properties of determinants
$$\det(A\cdot B) = (\det A)(\det B)\text{.}$$

Comment: That was exactly my question. I am afraid I don't see why this is the chain rule. what  is$\frac{\partial\Phi_{t}(x)}{\partial\Phi_{2}(x)}$?

Comment: "$s$", not "$2$".  It's the rate of change of $\Phi_t(x)$ with respect to $\Phi_s(x)$ (where $x$ is treated as the independent variable).  You should be familiar with the [chain rule in Leibniz notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule): $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}y} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$.  The dependency of $\Phi_t$ on $\Phi_s$ is given explicitly in the line of text between the two displays in your first unsearchable photograph.

Comment: The "2" is just a typo, sorry. Yes I am familiar with it, but not a fan. Okay, but doesn't $\Phi_{t+s}(x)=\Phi_{t}(\Phi_{s}(x))$ imply that $\frac{\partial\Phi_{t+s}(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial\Phi_{t}(x)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial\Phi_{s}(x)}{\partial x}$? Is it the case that $y$ is defined to be $y=\Phi_{s}(x)$? How do you get $\frac{\partial\Phi_{t}(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial\Phi_{t}(x)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial\Phi_{s}(x)}{\partial x}$?

Comment: *  Is it the case that $y$ is defined to be $y=\Phi_{s}(x)$, in other words it is a change of cooridnates?

Comment: It is the case that $y$ is the function between $\Phi_t$ and $x$ in the **chain** (/composition) of functions.